# Create one file per line via shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I have a file containing list of filenames, like this

```
file1.cfg
file2.cfg
file3.cfg
```

I want, using the linux terminal, to split this into `n` files with the given filename, each also containing the filename as a string.

For example, after transformation I want the content of `file1.cfg` to be

```
filename=file1.cfg
```

and in `file2.cfg`

```
filename=file2.cfg
```

etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your file is called `configs`, you can achieve this with

```
for i in $(cat configs); do echo "filename=$i">$i; done
```

Comment: for will work for simple file names, but might have issues if there are spaces in the file names.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that you count `awk` as shell, this is simply

```
awk '{print "filename="$0 >$0}' file.cfg
```

Comment: To make this space-safe, use $0 instead of $1 - and add "filename=".

Comment: Thanks, @KarstenS.; I just altered the answer.  I'm so used to using `awk` for field manipulation I think I just reached for `$1` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
while read line; do echo "filename=$line" > $line; done < file
```

it will open the file, read it line by line, and for each line it will create a file with the name being the content of the line and then write a line to that file with the contents of the `echo` command (being filename=).
caveat: I haven't actually tested it.